# How can I detect if a jQuery .append has already been applied

Tags: jquery

I have code that appends as follows:

```
if (json.expData[i] != null) {
    $('#text' + i)
    .append("<br><br><img src='/balloon.png'>" + json.expData[i]);
}
```

When a user clicks on a button this code runs and appends. However if the user clicks on the button again it appends once more and so on.

Is there some way that I could detect that the data has already been appended and only
make it add if it's the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store a boolean attribute on the element, such as `data-isappended`.

```
if (json.expData[i] != null) {
    var $text = $('#text' + i);
    if (!($text.data("isappended"))){
       $text.append("<br><br><img src='/balloon.png'>" + json.expData[i]);
       $text.data("isappended", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This give me an error: $text.data("isappended") = true; SCRIPT5003: Cannot assign to a function result

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is an `img` tag inside `#text`, that should do it

```
if ($('#text' + i).find('img').length > 0) 
{
    $('#text' + i).append("<br><br><img src='/balloon.png' />" + json.expData[i]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any other element with `id` contains `#text` then you can try like this:

```
if( $('[id^=text]').length ) { // if some element with id text exists 

} else { // not exists

}
```